# How to find coefficient that will minimize the distance between few times series

Tags: r, time-series, optimization, extreme-value

I have 3 time series X1, X2, X3. 
I want to find the coefficient (c1, c2) that will minimize the distance between them as follow:
$$MIN\sum\sqrt{(X1-(c1*X2+c2*X3))^2}$$

The constrains are:
$$-1< c1,c2 < 1$$

How can I do it in R?

Comment: There are a few ways to minimize functions in R. One of the most commonly used is 'optim()'. Write a function that takes a vector of c1 and c2 as the first argument. Pass the time series vectors in separately however you want. Then use it with `method = "L-BFGS-B"`, `lower = -1`, and `upper = 1`. This will set the numeric optimization method to one that can handle your constraints. If everything breaks, you may want to consider recoding your time series as plain old vectors (haven't tested this). I'm not at my laptop, but if you still need help after, I can write the code in an answer later.

Answer (score 2):

Andreas Brandmaier has developed an approach to evaluating pairs of time series that generates a complexity- and information theoretic-based distance function which he calls *Permutation Distance Clustering* (PDC). In addition, he has developed several R modules that perform his methodology:

1) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdc/pdc.pdf

2) https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i05/v067i05.pdf

3) http://scidok.sulb.uni-saarland.de/volltexte/2012/4545/pdf/Andreas_M_Brandmaier_Dissertation.pdf

Here's a quote from the abstract to article 2):

> The dissimilarity of time series is formalized as the squared
>   Hellinger distance between the permutation distribution of embedded
>   time series. The resulting distance measure has linear time
>   complexity, is invariant to phase and monotonic transformations, and
>   robust to outliers.

This quote does not mention that his approach does not rely on moment-based measures such as the mean, std dev, etc, which are the basis of traditional approaches to estimating distance functions, e.g., Euclidean distance, adding additional robustness to the methodology.

In addition, the introduction to paper 1) goes into some depth about how distance functions are used in cross-sectional approaches to clustering. For all intents and purposes, these notes related to clustering can be ignored as not being directly relevant to your objective.

Given 3 time series for your data, you would want to execute 3 comparisons: x1 with x2, x1 with x3 and x2 with x3. The key metric is the squared Hellinger distance function that is a direct by-product of this approach.